# Dynamically add one year to input type month based on another input type month using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have two input type of month. What I want to happen is when I input a date to the first field, the second field will automatically be filled with the same month and a year ahead. How can I achieve this using javascript? Thank you.

```
Start date: <input type='month' name='fromdate'> to <input type='month' name='deadline'>
```

**Note**: I need to use input type month, and please don't recommend to me that I use jquery's datepicker because it uses textbox.

Comment: Might take a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: can you provide an example of your input date and expected output?

Comment: @ucdream - check this : http://jsfiddle.net/7FAjy/ . Though I'm sure the javascript code is still a long way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the code through which you can get your required purpose

```
<script>
function getDateAhead()
{
    var str = document.getElementById('fromDate').value;
    var res = str.split("-");
    var newdate = (parseInt(res[0])+1)+"-"+res[1]
    console.log(str);
    console.log(newdate);
    document.getElementById('toDate').value = newdate;
}
</script>
<input type="month" id="fromDate" onChange="getDateAhead()"/>
<input type="month" id="toDate"/>
```

**Update**

```
<script>
function getDateAhead()
{
    var str = document.getElementById('fromDate').value;
    var res = str.split("-");
var year = parseInt(res[0])+1;    
var month = parseInt(res[1])-1;
    if (month <= 9 && month > 0 )
    {
        month = "0"+month;
    }
    else if (month == 0)
    {
        month = "12";  
        year = year - 1;
    }
    var newdate = year+"-"+month;
    console.log(str);
    console.log(newdate);
    document.getElementById('toDate').value = newdate;
}
</script>
<input type="month" id="fromDate" onChange="getDateAhead()"/>
<input type="month" id="toDate"/>
```

Working **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BluAngel/DAcTK/2/)**

Comment: Yeah. This is it, but can you make the month one less? For example, my input is March 2014, the next field will be February 2015. If you do, I'll mark your answer correct.

Comment: What you want in second field if in first field is `January 2014`?
Either `December 2014` or `January 2015`

Comment: If the first field for example is January 2014, it will be December 2014. If March 2014 is in the first field, the second field will be February 2015.

Comment: check now is this what you want?

Comment: You can simplify the function by valueAsNumber like function getDateAhead() { document.querySelector('#toDate').valueAsNumber = document.querySelector('#fromDate').valueAsNumber + 11; }

Comment: @int32_t thats great i didn't know that before thanks

Answer (score 1):

This JS uses the date object to calculate the `deadline`. 
The deadline date is always the last day of the previous month in the next year. `deadline` contains a full date object with the deadline date for further using.

```
document.getElementsByName('fromDate')[0].addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    var fromDate = new Date(e.target.value);
    var deadline = new Date(fromDate.getFullYear(), fromDate.getMonth(), fromDate.getDate()-1);
    document.getElementsByName('deadline')[0].value = deadline.getFullYear() + '-' + ((deadline.getMonth()+1).toString().length < 2 ? '0' + (deadline.getMonth()+1).toString() : deadline.getMonth()+1);
});
```

**<kbd>[JSfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/EhQLY/)</kbd>**