# Automatic Date Calculator without button

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is my HTML code:
[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nUGM.png)

```
<div class="input-field col  s12">
    <label for="PMDate">PM Date</label></br>
    <input type="Date" name="PMDate" id="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" required>
</div>
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <label for="Period">PM Period</label></br>
    <select name="Period" id="period">
        <option value="Annually">Annually</option>
        <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
        <option value="Quarterly">Quarterly</option>
        <option value="HalfYear">Half-Year</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <label for="NPMDate">Next PM Date</label></br>
    <input type="date" name="NPMDate" id="npmdate" readonly>
</div>
```

This is my Script: 
[JavaScript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oC1wF.png)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        onSelect:function (selectedPeriod) {
            if (this.id == 'period') {
                var period = document.getElementById("period").selectedIndex;
                var startDate = $('#date').datepicker("getDate");
                if (period == "Annually") {
                    var result = new Date(startDate.getFullYear() + 1, startDate.getMonth(), startDate.getDate());
                    document.getElementById("npmdate").innerHTML = result;
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

This is the UI snippet:
[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6wbL.png)

I want the Next PM date able to automatically generate out calculated date from PM date and PM Period. Where the user chosen a date and period. the calculation automatically display it's result before pressing the 'Save' button to insert all of the input records into the database. So far the calculation can't be displayed out. I need help.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and replace the pictures with the actual code. Also, if I understand your question correctly, you need to add an `onChange` handler to your input fields.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically add one year to input type month based on another input type month using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190825/dynamically-add-one-year-to-input-type-month-based-on-another-input-type-month-u)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER** 
Thank you Paras Raiyani

HTML Code:

```
<div class="input-field col  s12">
<label for="PMDate">PM Date</label></br>
<input type="date" id="PMDate" name="PMDate" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d') ?>" required>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s12">
<label for="Period">PM Period</label></br>
<select id="period" name="Period">
<option value="Annually">Annually</option>
<option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
<option value="Quarterly">Quarterly</option>
<option value="HalfYear">Half-Year</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s12">
<label for="NPMDate">Next PM Date</label></br>
<input type="date" id="NPMDate" name="NPMDate" readonly>
</div>
```

Script Function:

```
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"  
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#period').change(function(){
            var period=this.value;
            var start_date=new Date($('#PMDate').val());
            console.log(start_date);
            if(period=='Annually'){
                var result_date=new Date(start_date.getFullYear()+1, start_date.getMonth(), start_date.getDate());
                result_date=moment(result_date).format('Y-MM-DD');
                $('#NPMDate').val(result_date);
            }
            else if(period=='Monthly'){
                var result_date=new Date(start_date.getFullYear(), start_date.getMonth()+1, start_date.getDate());
                result_date=moment(result_date).format('Y-MM-DD');
                $('#NPMDate').val(result_date);
            }
            else if(period=='Quarterly'){
                var result_date=new Date(start_date.getFullYear(), start_date.getMonth()+3, start_date.getDate());
                result_date=moment(result_date).format('Y-MM-DD');
                $('#NPMDate').val(result_date);
            }
            else if(period=='HalfYear'){
                var result_date=new Date(start_date.getFullYear(), start_date.getMonth()+6, start_date.getDate());
                result_date=moment(result_date).format('Y-MM-DD');
                $('#NPMDate').val(result_date);
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :- this is only Annually calculation**

```
<input type="date" id="PMDate" name="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d') ?>">
<select id="period" name="period">
    <option value="Annually">Annually</option>
    <option value="Monthly" selected>Monthly</option>
    <option value="Quarterly">Quarterly</option>
    <option value="Half-Year">Half-Year</option>
</select>
<input type="date" id="NPMDate" name="npmdate" readonly>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#period').change(function(){
                var period=this.value;
                var start_date=new Date($('#PMDate').val());
                console.log(start_date);

                if(period=='Annually'){
                    var result_date=new Date(start_date.getFullYear()+1+'-'+ start_date.getMonth()+'-'+start_date.getDate());
                    result_date=moment(result_date).format('Y-MM-DD');
                    $('#NPMDate').val(result_date);
                }
        })
    });
</script>>
```

Comment: To change it monthly, should it be 
`var result_date=new Date(start_date.getFullYear()+'-'+ start_date.getMonth()+1+'-'+start_date.getDate());`

Cause the output give me Nov 6th from the original date of Feb 6th